# How do I change the directory but still write to existing file?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a script that creates a text file, and saves everything I need to save. The problem comes after I make a cycle and change the directory to upload files in another directory, but the text file is left in the old directory.

How can I change the directory but still write to the text file? This is my code:

```
kolekcija.each do |fails|
  @b.send_keys :tab
  @b.span(:class => "btnText", :text => "Save", :index => 1).when_present.click
  @b.frame(:id, "uploadManagerFrame").table(:id, "ctrlGetUploadedFiles_gvUploadedFiles").wait_until_present
  sleep 30

  # I need to edit it so it opens the TXT file in its existing location
  output = File.open("#{Time.now.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")} DemoUser.txt", "a") 
  output.puts ""
  output.puts "Korpusā ielādētais fails:  #{File.basename(@fails)} augšuplādēts sekmīgi..."
  output.close
  progress.increment
end
```

Comment: If you need to know where the file is, then tell Ruby exactly where to put it using an absolute path and filename, not a relative filename alone. Also, use the block form of `File.open`, i.e., `File.open(...) do ... end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll edit this if the question changes, because as is it's not clear; I don't see any change of directory, so I'm assuming that the user:

1. Changes directory somewhere in there.
2. Wants to continue appending information to the same text document.

If that's true, the answer is going to be either to use an absolute path to the text file:

```
file = File.open("/full/path/to/file", "a")
kolekcija.each do |fails|
  # ...
  file.puts "some stuff"
  # ...
end
file.close
```

If you're doing these long `sleep`s, that might be a problem, but you could also hold on to the path:

```
path = "/full/path/to/file"
kolekcija.each do |fails|
  # ...
  file = File.open(path, "a")
  file.puts "some stuff"
  file.close    
  # ...
end
```

Or use a [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) block in the part of the script where you want to change the directory to something else and back:

```
Dir.chdir(ENV["HOME"])  # now you're in your home directory ~
Dir.chdir("files") do   # now in ~/files
  upload_files
end                     # aaand you're back home
file = File.open("/full/path/to/file", "a")
file.puts "stuff"
file.close
```

I'll admit I'm not 100% sure about what the question is asking, but the solution is either going to be holding on to the filehandle, using an absolute path, or changing back to the original directory before writing to the text file.

Comment: +1 I think you nailed the issues. Looks like the OP is moving to different directories before running the script so the text file is always written relative to the current directory.

Comment: Thx the Dir.chdir helped me to make the script jump to the right dir after the text input in file. Now script works like charm !